# How to make a function return a specific number of digits

Tags: r, function, output, rounding

I've been using a function to calculate t-tests using the means, standard deviations and n in each condition.

```
ttest <- function(m1,m2,s1,s2,n1,n2,m0=0,equal.variance=FALSE)
{
  if( equal.variance==FALSE ) 
  {
    se <- sqrt( (s1^2/n1) + (s2^2/n2) )
    df <- ( (s1^2/n1 + s2^2/n2)^2 )/( (s1^2/n1)^2/(n1-1) + (s2^2/n2)^2/(n2-1) )
  } else
  {
    se <- sqrt( (1/n1 + 1/n2) * ((n1-1)*s1^2 + (n2-1)*s2^2)/(n1+n2-2) ) 
    df <- n1+n2-2
  }      
  t <- (m1-m2-m0)/se 
  sdpooled_n <- ((n1-1)*(s1^2)) + ((n2-1)*(s2^2)) 
  sdpooled_df <- ((n1 + n2) - 2) # 115
  sdpooled <- sqrt(sdpooled_n/sdpooled_df) 
  cohend <- (m1-m2)/sdpooled
  dat <- c(m1-m2, se, t, df,2*pt(-abs(t),df),cohend)    
  names(dat) <- c("Mean difference", "Std Error", "t","df", "p-value","Cohen's d")
  return(dat) 
}
```

It works great, but R annoyingly returns the results using scientific notation. For example, this code:

```
ttest(1.44,1.02,0.80,0.75,133,123,m0=0,equal.variance=FALSE)
```

Returns:

```
Mean difference  Std Error     t             df             p-value         Cohen's d 
4.200000e-01     9.687725e-02  4.335383e+00  2.539507e+02   2.099250e-05    5.409679e-01
```

It would be great if, instead, it would return this:

```
  Mean difference  Std Error     t             df             p-value         Cohen's d 
  0.42             0.10          4.34          253.95         0.000           0.54
```

I have tried using the round() function (see below), and it works perfectly except it only shows two decimal places for the p-value. It is important that I report the exact p-value unless p<.001.

This is my better and modified version of the code:

```
ttest <- function(m1,m2,s1,s2,n1,n2,m0=0,equal.variance=FALSE)
{
  if( equal.variance==FALSE ) 
  {
    se <- sqrt( (s1^2/n1) + (s2^2/n2) )
    df <- ( (s1^2/n1 + s2^2/n2)^2 )/( (s1^2/n1)^2/(n1-1) + (s2^2/n2)^2/(n2-1) )
  } else
  {
    se <- sqrt( (1/n1 + 1/n2) * ((n1-1)*s1^2 + (n2-1)*s2^2)/(n1+n2-2) ) 
    df <- n1+n2-2
  }      
  mdif <- m1-m2
  t <- (mdif-m0)/se 
  sdpooled_n <- ((n1-1)*(s1^2)) + ((n2-1)*(s2^2)) 
  sdpooled_df <- ((n1 + n2) - 2) # 115
  sdpooled <- sqrt(sdpooled_n/sdpooled_df) 
  cohend <- (m1-m2)/sdpooled
  p <- 2*pt(-abs(t),df)
  mdif <- round(mdif,2)
  se <- round(se,2)
  t <- round(t,2)
  df <- round(df,2)
  p <- round(p,3)
  cohend <- round(cohend,2)
  dat <- c(mdif, se, t, df,p,cohend)
  names(dat) <- c("Mean difference", "Std Error", "t","df", "p-value","Cohen's d")
  return(dat) 
}
```

But as you can see, it doesn't return the p-value to 3 decimal places:

```
Mean difference  Std Error  t      df       p-value   Cohen's d 
0.42             0.10       4.34   253.95   0.00      0.54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `dat` inside your first ttest function as follow:

```
dat <-round(c(m1-m2, se, t, df,2*pt(-abs(t),df),cohend) , digits =2 )
```

Best wishes!